# How to return list of installed Apps in alphabetical order

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

In my Android project, I am trying to return a list of user-installed and system apps **alphabetically** in two fragments within an actionbaractivity in scrollable tabs

I used an custom adapter class to get the list of apps and have code to return either user-installed or pre-installed apps in the listview. However, I am trying to return them in both alphabetical order.

I am trying to follow these but no luck.

http://www.androprogrammer.com/2013/10/list-view-with-check-box-using-custom.html

[Alphabetize List of Installed Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900688/alphabetize-list-of-installed-apps)

Right now I have this as my Adapter Class:

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.R;

import java.util.List;

public class ApkAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    List<PackageInfo> packageList;
    Activity context;
    PackageManager packageManager;
    boolean[] itemChecked;

    public ApkAdapter(Activity context, List<PackageInfo> packageList,
                      PackageManager packageManager) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.packageList = packageList;
        this.packageManager = packageManager;
        itemChecked = new boolean[packageList.size()];
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView apkName;
        CheckBox ck1;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return packageList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return packageList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.appname);
            holder.ck1 = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
             //holder.ck1.setTag(packageList.get(position));

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        // ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);

        Drawable appIcon = packageManager
                .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
        String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
                packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
        appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 75, 75);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
        holder.apkName.setText(appName);
        holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

        if (itemChecked[position])
            holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
        else
            holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

        holder.ck1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (holder.ck1.isChecked())
                    itemChecked[position] = true;
                else
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }



}
```

And here is one of my java classes. This one is for returning the user-installed apps:

```
package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;

import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app.ApkAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class InstalledAppActivity extends Fragment
        implements OnItemClickListener {

    PackageManager packageManager;
    ListView apkList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_installed, container, false);
        packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
                .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        List<PackageInfo> packageList1 = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();

        /*To filter out System apps*/
        for(PackageInfo pi : packageList) {
            boolean b = isSystemPackage(pi);
            if(!b) {
                packageList1.add(pi);
            }
        }
        apkList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.applist);
        apkList.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(getActivity(), packageList1, packageManager));

        apkList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return rootView;

    }

    /**
     * Return whether the given PackgeInfo represents a system package or not.
     * User-installed packages (Market or otherwise) should not be denoted as
     * system packages.
     *
     * @param pkgInfo
     * @return boolean
     */
    private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true
                : false;
    }


// Don't need in Fragment
/*@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.block, menu);
   // super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}*/

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sort lists in Java, the simplest way is to use [`Collections.sort()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E%29). You just need an appropriate `Comparator<?>`.

I assume you want to sort by *application name*. In that case you can use something like this:

```
final PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator comparator = new PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager);

Collections.sort(packageList1, new Comparator<PackageInfo>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(PackageInfo lhs, PackageInfo rhs)
    {
        return comparator.compare(lhs.applicationInfo, rhs.applicationInfo);
    }
});
```

If you want to sort by *package name*, it's even simpler:

```
Collections.sort(packageList1, new Comparator<PackageInfo>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(PackageInfo lhs, PackageInfo rhs)
    {
        return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(lhs.packageName, rhs.packageName);
    }
});
```

Comment: How should I implement this in my case

Comment: @XiJiaopin Just include one of these two versions (for whichever sort order you want) _before_ you do `apkList.setAdapter()`